# ZendSoapServer looses Error Code when throwing an Exception / SoapFault

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception, soap, error-code

I have a Zend Backend & a Zend Frontend, both communicating over SOAP. An Exception on the backend, should throw an Exception / SoapFault on the Frontend. This works with the Error-Message, but the Error-Code gets lost somehow. I need the code to be able to show errors in different languages on the frontend. I tried a lot, but couldnt get it to work.

**This is the Backend handleSoap function of my SoapController:**

```
private function handleSOAP($class) {
    $options = array('uri' => 'urn:'.$class.'','location' => $this->_WSDL_URI);
    $server = new Zend_Soap_Server(null, $options);
    $server->setEncoding('ISO-8859-1');
    $server->setClass($class);
    $server->registerFaultException('Exception');
    $server->handle();  
}
```

**On the Frontend the SoapCallerClass:**

```
        public function __construct() {
            $this->client = new Zend_Soap_Client($this->_WSDL_URI);
            $this->client->setWsdlCache(WSDL_CACHE_NONE);
            $this->client->setEncoding('ISO-8859-1');
    }

    public function __call($method,$params) {
       try {
         $this->client->mySoapFunction();    
       } catch (Exception $e)  {
       throw $e; // No error code inside !
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the SoapFault object passed to the Frontend. Using getMessage() returns the original message. Using getCode returns 0, but the object has a property called faultcode and faultmessage that contain the original code & message of the exception.